# > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore]

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to add the   ***cloud_firestore***: ^4.8.3 in my flutter project , but when I try to run the project with the command `flutter run` it displays to me this error:

```
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] /Users/medyassinemessaoud/Documents/EspritSim/flutter/examples/delivery-1/build/cloud_firestore/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
```

Such that my **build.gradle** is like that:

```
def flutterMinSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
if (flutterMinSdkVersion == null) {
  flutterMinSdkVersion = 23
}

 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deliveryapp"
        minSdkVersion flutterMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

also the **local.properties** is like that:

`flutter.compileSdkVersion=23`
But with the same error, how can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the minSDK from

> minSdkVersion flutterMinSdkVersion

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deliveryapp"
        minSdkVersion 21 //this
```

Comment: Same problem , nothing change

Comment: can you switch back to default and just change this line

Answer (score 0):

The `minSdkVersion` declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file of the `cloud_firestore` library is set to **19**, while your Flutter project's `minSdkVersion` is set to **16**. This conflict occurs because your project's minimum SDK version is lower than what the library requires.

Update your project's `minSdkVersion` to meet the requirements of the `cloud_firestore` library. In your `build.gradle` file, change the `minSdkVersion` to 19 or higher:

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    minSdkVersion 19 //at least 19 or higher
    // ...
}
```

If you must maintain a `minSdkVersion` of 16 for your project, you can try using an older version of the `cloud_firestore` library that supports SDK 16. You can modify your `pubspec.yaml` file to specify a lower version:

```yaml
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4
```

Comment: Same problem , nothing change

Answer (score 0):

In file **local.properties**, change

> flutter.minSdkVersion=19

Or maybe try to upgrate other dependencies:

- remove file **pubspec.lock**
- `flutter clean & flutter pub get`

Comment: Same problem , nothing change